# Can't receive file_get_contents('php://input'); with data sent with curl

Tags: php, curl

I've been reading some answers, but nothing seems to help in my case, or I'm not able to understand it completelly.
I've got this curl POST, that is working as I can see throught firebug, it sends 1,5MB and I can see the `200 OK`

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $my_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

On the `$my_url` file on another server where I should receive the data I use

```
$postdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

But Im not receiving anything, I've added

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

as someone suggested in some answers, but still it's not working.

The server who receives the POST has `php 5.2.17` I'm not sure if I should activate anything.
Can you helping finding my error, or could you suggest me a different way to send that data?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I have readed that php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data", but I don't now if Im using enctype="multipart/form-data", how can I check it?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);` I need to send `$data`

Note: Not sure if I should delete this question or not.

Comment: Don't delete. Approve your own answer tomorrow so people with same problem can also find the solution.